# Cleaning up AD Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to automate more in my environment. Right now I have the following script that compares a csv file to AD and exports a list of new users that need created. I want to expand on this and disable any user that is found in AD and not the csv.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$results = @()
$results = ForEach ($User in (Import-Csv c:\scripts\adusers.csv)) {
$userName = $User.ID
$sch = $User.DEPT
$first = $User.FN
$last = $user.LN
$pass = $User.BDATE
$yog = $User.GRD
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Username = $userName
    School = $sch
    First = $first
    Last = $last
    Password = $pass
    YOG = $yog
    Found = [boolean]((Get-ADUser -filter {samaccountname -eq $userName}) -ne $null)
    }
}
$results | where {-not $_.found} | Select Username,School,First,Last,Password,YOG | 
   Export-Csv c:\Scripts\newusers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How big is your AD? Is it feasible to run `$ADUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter *; $ADUsers | ?{$_.samAccountName -notin (Import-CSV C:\scripts\adusers.csv).ID}`?

Comment: What about all the service user accounts and Admin accounts and things?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician my environment isn't that big. I'll try what you suggested and report back